# There's a problem on my code about cs50 in mario problem

Tags: cs50

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK7If.png)
Hello, I was coding for cs50 in the    *`mario`*    problem but it seems that there is an error that says:

```
             ^
mario.c:20:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'k'
 for (k = 1; k <= n - i; k++){
                         ^
3 errors generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'mario' failed
make: *** [mario] Error 1
```

Why is this so? :/

Comment: Try to write int before the first k.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't declared the variable `k` anywhere.

Usually, in a for loop, the iterator variable is declared at the start. For example,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
  // code to run
}
```

In your code, you haven't declared 'k' by explicitly stating `int k = 0;` Hence, to fix your code, try adding an `int` (to declare the variable `k` as an int) before the first `k`.